# Masstransit 7.2.1 problem with custom health checks on program start

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit, health-check

With MassTransit 7.2.1 I got a null pointer exeception in combination with custom health checks :

The endpoint for /health was added:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(
            endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });
```

Some custom health checks like for Elasticstack, Consul, Redis etc. was configured as service too (available on "health/elasticstack"), i.e.:

```
        healthChecksBuilder.AddElasticsearch(
            uriSettings,
            serviceSettings.Name,
            HealthStatus.Degraded,
            new[] { serviceSettings.Service, });
```

At the beginning I got an exception once:

(a) First exception

```
    StackTrace  "   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceiveEndpointCollection.<>c.<CheckHealth>b__11_3(<>f__AnonymousType56`2 x) in /home/runner/work/MassTransit/MassTransit/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceiveEndpointCollection.cs:line 116"   string
```

(b) Followup exeception

```
    StackTrace  "   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in /_/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/TcpClientAdapter.cs:line 23"  string
```

After skipping the exception the health check reports "Healthy" after a while

If the "endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health")" part is removed, it works? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was [resolved](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2645) and should be in the next release.